# How can a "new contributor" have over 600 reputation?

Tags: discussion, new-contributor-indicator

I feel like this person is fortunate enough to not be considered "new" to the site anymore...

[image: Ben. Ayoub]

...so my real question is, why is this indicator attached to this person?  They have enough reputation to get them what I'd perceive to be the "new person" initiation period.

Comment: He started earning rep [4 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10434643/ben-ayoub?tab=reputation).

Comment: @HansPassant:  Actually, thanks for that.  There's a bit *more* to this person and their reputation gain.  Something's fishy here and it started with that contributor icon.

Comment: we should add a new badge: *New contributor BOSS* : reach 1K while keeping the new contributor icon visible.

Comment: And he promptly lost 220 rep again, tall trees catch a lot of wind.

Comment: @HansPassant he lost even more ... on his way back to 1rep

Answer (score 2):

Because they've only been on the site for a week. Reputation and answer experience doesn't factor into whether that message is shown. (You probably don't need to go easy on someone who can earn 600 rep that quickly.)

Comment: Something seems fishy though.  Some of their more recent answers may be suspect...

Comment: (We don't need to go easy on anyone, regardless of body parts shown.)

Comment: @Makoto Jon Skeet rep-capped on his first day. If you suspect a voting ring, though, Meta is not the place for that.

Comment: @StephenLeppik:  I am *well* aware of that.  It simply hadn't occurred to me in the heat of the moment to look at their reputation gain chart.  I'm not demanding anyone go on a fishing expedition or anything like that related to this person.  I just simply said something seemed fishy.